# ssh access: why cannot I login without typing the password?

Tags: shell, ssh

I am using the SSH secure shell to login my remote Linux servers.
I just wonder why I have to manually typein the password any time I login and cannot store it ?

I tried putty and it seems, you also cannot store the password.
As I have various Linux servers to manage, is there a simple way to login without manually typing the password ?

Regards

Comment: [ssh-agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) might be what you're after

Comment: @sje397 On Windows, the best implementation of ssh-agent functionality is PuTTY's Pageant.

Answer (score 6):

Use SSH-Public-Key Authentication with your PuTTY. More information here:

http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey